# unable to find valid certification path to requested target, even after adding CA certificates

Tags: java, spring-boot, docker-compose, openssl, ssl-certificate

This is my code which imports ca certificate through api, but after importing certificates, it still gives the error as:

"""unable to find valid certification path to requested target; nested exception is javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: PKIX path building failed""""..
I have verified that that the certificates have been successfully imported but still gives the error.
Code:

InputStream certIn = certificateFile.getInputStream();
final char sep = File.separatorChar;
File dir = new File(System.getProperty("java.home") + sep + "lib" + sep + "security");
File file = new File(dir, "cacerts");
InputStream localCertIn = new FileInputStream(file);

```
    KeyStore keystore = KeyStore.getInstance(KeyStore.getDefaultType());
    keystore.load(localCertIn, keyStorePassword.trim().toCharArray());
    if (keystore.containsAlias(certAliasName.trim())) {
        certIn.close();
        localCertIn.close();
        return new ResponseEntity<String>("Certificate Alias Name Already Exist", HttpStatus.CONFLICT);
    }
    localCertIn.close();

    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(certIn);
    CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");
    while (bis.available() > 0) {
        Certificate cert = cf.generateCertificate(bis);
        keystore.setCertificateEntry(certAliasName.trim(), cert);
    }

    certIn.close();

    OutputStream out = new FileOutputStream(file);
    keystore.store(out, keyStorePassword.trim().toCharArray());
    out.close();
```

The alternate solution i found that we need to restart docker container everytime when we add a new certificate, but at production level we cannot do that, Is there anyone who can help in this?

Comment: You say "importing certificates" and "verifying ... certificates". In English this plural implies there is more than one cert (PEM block) in `certificateFile.getInputStream()` -- is there? If there is, because you store each of them in `certAliasName.trim()` each one (after the first) overwrites and replaces the previous one, so only the last one is left in the updated store.

Comment: Hey, yes there are more than one pem file, and each is getting overriden by the new one, can you suggest some solution,?

Comment: If you want/need all of them, use a unique alias for each. If you are using the default TrustManager it doesn't depend on any particular alias value, so one way I have used is sequential numbers: 1, 2, 3, 4, etc which are very easy to generate.

Comment: Hey found the solution, yeah this alias was creating a problem though but found it, thank you